Home page stuck in redirect loop, but static page it references loads fine
I have a home page stuck in a 301 redirect loop.
Symptoms

The site is configured to display a static page. If I change it to display the most recent posts, they display correctly.
It does not matter which static page I have set as the home page, none of them render correctly as the home page.
The static pages render just fine when I view them directly (eg, https://example.com/home-page/)
Doesn't matter which theme is active, the homepage behaves the same way.

What I've Tried

Reinstalling my theme from fresh download (then realized other themes behave the same)
Changing Themes
Uploading fresh copies of all Wordpress Core files.
Regenerating permalinks
Deleting customizations from htacess
Disabling all plugins


SOLVED! The 301 redirect loop problem ended up getting resolved by changing Cloudflare's SSL settings from "Flexible" to "Strict"
